# Firebase app distribution with gradle while having multiple flavorDimensions

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-app-distribution

In the app, there is 2 flavorDimensions and for each pair there is seperate firebase project. Is there any way to set up firebaseAppDistribution for each one of them?

Comment: I think this is better solution for your problem https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects

Comment: This does not help as service account json key file has to be refferenced from gradle.

Comment: why json is being referenced from gradle?

Comment: its how documentation asks https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-gradle#step_3_configure_your_distribution_properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used CI script to replace servcie account key json file for each flavor and it works.

Still don't know how to solve it without replacing json manually or with script.